# How can I show pinyin on top of characters using PySide?

Tags: python, cjk, pyside6, pinyin

Image of pinyin on top of Chinese characters.:
[image: Image of pinyin on top of Chinese characters]

I have a string of Chinese characters and their respective pinyin. Is there any way I can display them as text like in the image above with PySide?

I have tried something like this for the CSS part:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As for the HTML part:

```
<span>wǒ<br>我</span><span>ài<br>爱</span><span>nǐ<br>你</span>
```

AFAIK, PyQt does not have full CSS support so the inline-block method does not work. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried before? How are you displaying the text?

Comment: @UmbralReaper Hi. Thanks for the reply. I've tried using "span {display: inline-block; text-align: center;}" for the CSS part. "<span>wǒ<br>我</span><span>ài<br>爱</span><span>nǐ<br>你</span>" for the HTML part.

AFAIK, PyQt does not have full CSS support so the inline-block method does not work.